# Filter Duplicate Record Items by Duplicate Rule

Tags: reporting, duplicate-management, custom-report-type

I have setup a "Duplicate Accounts" report following the [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_management_custom_report_types.htm&type=5) provided but I then realized this is based on a rule that matches on Billing Address. What I need is a duplicate accounts report based on Shipping Address (physical location).

I have setup a new matching and duplicate rule, but I'm not sure how to adjust my report or custom report type to filter the results to matches only from my new rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to **Edit Layout** for your **Custom Report Type** and use the **Add Fields related via Lookup**. You're going to want `Duplicate Record Set > Duplicate Rule > Rule Name`.

[image]

[image]